# Python Error For GCSE Practise

Tags: python-3.x

Code:

```
from array import *
from math import *
from string import *
from random import *
from time import *

arrayQueryCategories = [["cracked","screen","display","smashed","broken","dropped"],#BrokenScreen
                        ["wet","damp","moist","water","soaked","liquid"],#WetPhone
                        ["charging","power","battery","plug","won't"],#NotCharging
                        ["turn","on","off","activate","black"],#WontTurnOn
                        ["buttons","stuck","press","home","lock","volume","mute"],#ButtonsBroken
                        ["locked","out","time","wait","code","password","stuck","unlock","passcode"]]#LockedOut

def defSearchFor():
    global Result
    Result = []
    Query = input("Search Term: ")
    Query = Query.lower()
    Counter = 0
    while Counter < len(arrayQueryCategories):
        print(str(Counter))
        try:
            Result.append(arrayQueryCategories[Counter].index(Query))
            print("good")
        except ValueError:
            print("bad")
            Result.append(-1)
        Counter = Counter + 1
    print(str(Result))
    defRespondTo()

def defRespondTo():
    Responses = ["PlaceHolder-BrokenScreen","PlaceHolder-WetPhone"\
                 "PlaceHolder-NotCharging","PlaceHolder-WontTurnOn"\
                 "PlaceHolder-ButtonsBroken","PlaceHolder-Lockedout"]
    Counter = 0
    while Counter <= len(arrayQueryCategories):
        if Result[Counter] != -1:
            print(Responses[Counter])
            Counter = Counter + 1
            defSearchFor()


defSearchFor()
```

Result:

```
Search Term: broken
0
good
1
bad
2
bad
3
bad
4
bad
5
bad
[4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
PlaceHolder-BrokenScreen
Search Term: lock
0
bad
1
bad
2
bad
3
bad
4
good
5
bad
[-1, -1, -1, -1, 4, -1]
```

There is the code and the result. After that point the result just stops outputting, but there is no ">>>" to indicate that the process has finished. Why is it not relooping? The code should loop infinitely. What is the problem with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Your tests show that there is nothing wrong with `defSearchFor`

So look at `defRespondTo`  There is a loop there, that loops while `Counter <=6` , but `Counter` is only incremented inside the `if`.

When debugging, try to cut down as much code as possible. You don't need any imports and you know that the first function is working, so cut them out. Here is my minimal test version of your program. It has the same bug as yours, but it is easier to spot the error.

```
def defRespondTo():
    Counter = 0
    while Counter <= 6:
        if Result[Counter] != -1:
            print(Counter)
            Counter = Counter + 1     

Result = [-1,-1,-1,-1,4,-1]

defRespondTo()
```

Comment: thank you! This has made my task a whole lot easier, thanks!

Comment: If this has been useful, consider upvoting and accepting.